# Dynamic (Dependent) formula column in Dataverse table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Eager for integrity at the database level, I want to restrict data entry to tables only to pre-established lists of values. I need to create a formula column so that it is populated with pre-defined lists of options. My issue is that these pre-defined lists are already stored in separate tables. To refer to those tables via their names, the names were put in a column in the same Dataverse table.

(Main) Table: Plants:
Column: "Plant Category"
Column:Plant Type

Table Categories:{Fruit, Vegetable}

Table: Fruit: {Apple, Orange, Mango}

Table: Vegetable: {Tomato, Onion, Cucumber"

Column Plants.'Plant Category' is already lookedup to be populated with data in table "Categories".

I need the column Plants.'Plant Type' to be dependent on the the values in the column Plants.'Plant Category', which are names of the tables of "Fruit" and "Vegetable". So that when the column Plants.'Plan Category' = Fruite, the column Plants.'Plant Type' gives a list of fruits to choose from

Would you please provide me with the formula expression to be inserted in the definition of the column Plants.'Plant Type'.

[image]

I am new to Power apps. I have attempted to create a dynamic formula but could not.

Answer (score 0):

Put vegetables and fruit into one single table instead of two. Add a column for the Plant Category to that table, then you can simply filter the Fruit/Vegetable table by the Category provided and serve the result of the filter operation to the dropdown.